# Linq query to access data from xml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file containing some elements like

```
 <root>
    <gp>
      <i>1</i>
      <i>3</i>
      <i>5</i>
    </gp>
    <gp>
      <i>5</i>
      <i>6</i>
    </gp>
     . 
     . 
 </root>
```

Now i want to write a query by which i will get all `gp` elements which contains the `<i>`  element with value 5?`

Comment: Ienumerable<XElement> variable = document.Elements("gp").where( p => p. now here i got stuck because here we have to iterate <i> elements also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = from gp in doc.Descendants("gp")
              where gp.Elements("i").Any(i => (int)i == 5)
              select gp
```

And in method-based syntax:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("gp").Where(gp => gp.Elements("i").Any(i => (int)i == 5));
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `i.value == "5"`, I don't think you can convert XElement to int.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Yes you can, try it out

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Yes, you can. And not only to int: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx